# Logcat spamming phone processes into my feed

Tags: android, logcat

Whenever I connect my phone to the PC Logcat spams all the processes that the phone is performing. However when I launch the app that I am creating the logs reported are only to do with the app.

I just want to know how to stop it from spamming the feed when the app is not launched.

I tried going into the Android Device Manager and adding a new filter, but that has still not stopped it from spamming my feed.

I even uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studios but that did not help either.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic functionality of LogCat. When you leave it on Verbose, it displays every event from your phone. In the top right of the logcat window there is a set of three controls, a dropdown that allows you to select the log level, a text box, and another dropdown that says "show only selected application", "no filter", and "edit filter configuration". If you put gibberish, or just the package name of your app into the text box and hit return, LogCat will only display messages that match the pattern you entered in the textbox.

Comment: It wasn't doing that before, it somehow started when I initiated my app after including the BeanShell .jar file. I need to stop LogCat from spamming because my app keeps on crashing to and want to see the error. I get spammed with the phone's process as soon as it crashes.